# Disable plugins/libraries added to a PHP Laravel App when in Production mode?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

Is there a way to make a PHP Laravel app only register and user plugins when in dev/debug moode?  For example a library like https://github.com/asvae/laravel-api-tester which is like a Postman app built into Laravel to test your API route is something that I love to use however for performance it seems careless to load it in my production environment.

Obviously i'm not talking about 1-2 libraries but when there are many that are only used while in development, it would be nice to have them disable and not loaded into the app when we are in production mode.

So is there a built in way to handle this already?  If not, how would I go about manually disabling modules in production and turning them back on in debug mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the "**require-dev**" option of the composer.

https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#require

https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#require-dev

To add dependencies that are just developmental you should use something like:

```
composer require --dev asvae/laravel-api-tester
```

So in your production deploy script, you should add "**--no-dev**" so that the development dependencies are not installed.

You can also see which of your dependencies are in "require" and "require-dev" in your **composer.json** file.

Comment: Thanks your method should handle preventing the package files from loading however it doesn't take care of the service provider or façade entries in the `config/app.php` file.  I found this really cool package https://github.com/svenluijten/env-providers which allows you to have a new config file ``config/providers.php` with groups for each environment stage to define façade and service providers for each one